# How do I remove my tub diverter?

Tags: plumbing, valve

I replaced my cold and hot water valves a while back and now it seems like it's time to replace the diverter. When running the water to the tub, some water comes out of the shower head. I've tried to disassemble the diverter valve as much as I can but I can't get the stem out. I've tried spraying some penetrating oil in but nothing seems to budge.

So I guess my question is: what next? Does the stem just pull out at this point or is this large nut (~1 1/8") supposed to be removed first? I can't make either budge.

Here are some pictures.

Before:

[image: Before]

With cover removed:

[image: With cover removed]

Retaining piece:

[image: Retaining piece]

Stem with retaining piece removed:

[image: With retaining piece removed]

<sub>Click for full size image</sub>

Comment: I think you remove the shaft at this point, and it should have come out when you removed the large nut. Have you got a pipe wrench, or channel lock pliers? I would use one or both to try twisting the pipe to see if that breaks the pipe free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just got the diverter out of the wall. It turns out the diverter was threaded in and needed to be removed. Here's a picture of the full diverter. The piece on the upper-right was what needed to be un-threaded. A pair of vice grips and a hammer did the trick:

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to find a replacement, or did you just replace a seal?

Comment: I had to replace the whole set of valves behind the wall. There are a lot of places out there that have huge inventories but my specific one couldn't be matched anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I used a "shower valve socket wrench" to remove
the valve from the wall. My wrench size was 31/32".[image]